# SPARQL query to obtain rdfs:domain and rdfs:range of a wikidata property

Tags: sparql, wikidata, rdfs

I am trying to get the property constraints of wikidata property through SPARQL query but am unable to understand the required constraints set in wikidata. I am looking for values corresponding to rdfs:domain and rdfs:range for a property in wikidata if available, have someone done this before? Or anyone can help me in identifying the right constraints set in wikidata that can be obtained using API given a property id.

Comment: there is no domain/range for properties in Wikidata - the decided to use some different approach to model the schema instead of RDFS or OWL. The list of constraints and documentation can be found here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Property_constraints_portal

Comment: Ah ok, I had this intuition. Wanted to confirm on this. I had seen this property constraints earlier but very much confused on how it has to be used. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no domain/range for properties in Wikidata - they decided to use some different approach to model the schema instead of RDFS or OWL. The list of constraints and documentation can be found here: https://wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Property_constraints_portal